# purrr split %>% map %>% bind VERSUS dplyr group_by %>% do

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, purrr, split-apply-combine

I am often in the position of wanting to split-apply-combine regression models. I've found two ways of doing it, the "`purrr`" approach and the "`dplyr::do()`" approach.

Issue with the `purrr` approach: I want columns in the resulting data.frame to indicate the levels of the variables according to which the split was done, as in a normal `group_by %>%` summarize operation.

Issue with the `dplyr::do()` approach: there's a nasty tangle of `do(tidy(lm_robust))` that is decidedly inelegant. But I get the columns back.

**Main Q:** is there a way to do split-apply-combine in `purrr` that returns the variable splits nicely?

The minimum working example below shows that the problem interacts with how many variables you're splitting by.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(estimatr) # for lm_robust

# spliting by one variable

# the purrr approach
mtcars %>%
  split(.$am) %>%
  map(~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .)) %>%
  map_df(tidy, .id = "am") # annoying to have to type "am" again!

# the dplyr do() approach
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(tidy(lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .))) # gross nesting

# Splitting by two variables

# the purr approach??
mtcars %>%
  split(list(.$am, .$vs)) %>%
  map(~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .))  %>%
  map_df(tidy, .id = "OH NO") # the column encodes both am and vs info

# the dplyr do() approach works great
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  do(tidy(lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .))) # still nested up.
```

EDIT

here's a way that uses nest() and unnest(). clunky, but maybe the best purrr approach? inspired by http://stat545.com/block024_group-nest-split-map.html

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .)),
         tidy = map(fit, tidy)) %>%
  select(am, vs, tidy) %>%
  unnest(tidy)
```

EDIT 2

Here's a way with `group_map` that's just as ugly as `do`, but maybe that's just the way it goes.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  group_map(~tidy(lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .x)))
```

EDIT 3:

I guess what would seem beautiful to me would do one thing per line, something like this, but I respect the comments below saying, geez, group map is pretty close.

```
# does not work
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  map(~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .)) %>%
  map_df(tidy)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show how a code should look like for it mot be termed as `ugly`.  The `EDIT 2` is 3 steps, one `group_by` and a `group_map`

Comment: There are redundant steps in the approach in the first edit.  You can rewrite it more succinctly as: `mtcars %>% nest(-am, -vs) %>%   mutate(tidy = map(data, ~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, data = .) %>% tidy)) %>% unnest(tidy)`.

Comment: what's ugly about the `group_map` ? I can't imagine a much more compact approach, and it's quite readable to me. if it's really about the brace nesting you can try `group_map(~lm_robust(mpg ~ hp,.) %>% tidy)` on your last line

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but none of the examples you gave where you complained about nesting are nested for me

Comment: but anyway, you were looking for a pretty answer, so I gave one below! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

```
mtcars %>% reframe(tidy(lm_robust(mpg ~ hp, .)), .by = c(am, vs))
```